# VBA Reading Chart Series incorectly

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problematic chart in Excel that VBA for some reason messes up.
The list of values is too long to show here but its a simple row of values.
Conincidentally the values(cells) are alligned from left to right in following order:

Values greater than zero, zeros, empty cells

For some strange reason "locals" Window in VBE shows the values in following order:

Empty Cells, Values greater than zero, zeros

I know that this is not caused by my code becasue I tested this with multiple scripts like the example bellow:

```
Sub test_empty_series()
    Dim Series As Series
    Set Series = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
End Sub
```

Even worst is the fact that I cannot replicate the issue. Has anyone seen soemting like this, or similar problem?

Let me know if  you need more information becuase I am lost.

Comment: first- you should never declare your variables like this `Dim Series As Series`, use any unique name for your variable like `mySeries`, `chSeries`, whatever...what is your goal? where is relation between problem and code you showed us?

Comment: Code is just an example of I used to diagnose the issue. I want to know why are `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Value` not in order, please see above for real order(cells) and VBE's percieved order.

Comment: what if you iterate point after point? is it in right order?

Comment: No the iterator follows VBE's order, I should note that the chart itself has all values in correct order, only VBE has the issue.